# Tap-to-toggle menu in JavaScript (no JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website menu bar that has two separate divs that a site visitor can toggle between just by tapping. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kS7KE/70/) and the actual code:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="div">
    <div id="next1">MENU 1</div>
    <div id="next2">MENU 2</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container{
    height:100px;
    width:50%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#div{
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#next1{
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:green;
    position:absolute;
}
#next2{
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:100%;
    background:orange;
    position:absolute;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$("#next1").click(function () {
    targetLeft = "-100%";
    $("#div").animate({left: targetLeft},400);   
});
$("#next2").click(function () {
    targetLeft = "0";
    $("#div").animate({left: targetLeft},400);   
});
```

The code works well, but I'd like to do this without JQuery, and am wondering if anyone knows how this could be done? (If it can be done without JavaScript as well, that would be ideal but I'm not sure that's possible.)

Thanks for reading!

Comment: The code in your jsFiddle example doesn't match the code you posted

Comment: Thanks for catching that. The link should be updated now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [CSS3 transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) instead:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/cLs813pf/)

```
document.getElementById('next1').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('div').style.left = '-100%';
});
document.getElementById('next2').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('div').style.left = '0%';
});
```

```
#div {
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    left: 0;
    transition: left 400ms ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Josh, that second example is great. As the jsfiddle is now updated to match the posted code, please consider deleting the first example in your answer. Either way, answer accepted. Thanks!